# JPA performance optimization or alternatives

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

We are currently in a project with a high demand on performance when it comes to reads from the database.

We are currently using JPA (EclipseLink implementation), currently just because it provides convenient database access and column mapping.

For our queries we are using highly specific SQL queries. We are also using one database (SAP HANA, in-memory), so a language abstraction is not required. The database access is pretty fast, our current bottleneck really is the application server, especially the persistence layer.

The result sets often also do not contain entities because entities are made up of the context. For us, there is no point in using an @Id field like the following, because we don't have fields that are unique (only combinations, but defining an IdClass is too much overhead).

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    public myField;


    // other fields...
}
```

This seems to be enforced by JPA if I want to run a typed native query. Is that assumption true? Currently we haven't found a way around the ID mapping.

Are these findings valid? 
If not, how can we make our use of JPA more performant (there is significant latency compared to plain JDBC), also without defining an @Id (because it is useless in our case) for result types?
If yes, is there another Java library that just provides a minimum layer on top of JDBC without too much latency that provides a more convenient use than plain JDBC (with column mapping and all that good stuff).

Thanks!

Usecase: We would like to stream historic GPS sensor data from the database. Besides just transforming this to JSON, we also do some transformations/validations. That's why we actually need to build objects. So what we basically looking for is a convenient way of mapping the fields of select statements to attributes. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) is one alternative to using an ORM. Could you give some concrete examples of your performance problems with JPA vs plain JDBC?

Comment: [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) is another

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles and blogs about improving EclipseLink/JPA performance that you might look into, such as [EclipseLink Performance](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Performance), [JPA Performance Tuning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10108/toplink.htm#ASPER99836) and [Optimizing the EclipseLink Application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_(ELUG))

In the end though it all depends very much on your specific use case and any future use cases you may want.  JPA is designed to make reading and writing overtop of JDBC easier and more maintainable and adds many performance benefits such as caching.  If all you are using it for is to read raw data though, the extra layer might be extra overhead that isn't adding any value.  There isn't much point to having JPA build you entities from the resultsets, maintain the cache and watch for changes only for your application to ignore it all and grab the raw data.

I do not understand why you would have an Item table with a single myField.  How is it used by the application and how does it relate to other tables and potential entities?

Such a construct is not the normal use case for relational databases and ORMs, but there are still ways around it in JPA.  The data could be used in element collections by other entities, or even just not mapped, and native SQL queries used which are passed straight through the JDBC layer.  EclipseLink itself has many mapping types and options above and beyond JPA that might be used depending on your use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course, I don't want to map just one field, I though that this was obvious, sorry about that. I've updated my post to be more precise.

Comment: Entities require identity just as any database rows do.  If you plan to have relationships between entities, JPA will need to know what uniquely identifies an entity, and it allows allowing caching and performance enhancements you may want to use down the road.  If you are converting to JSON, the ID allows caching and looksups, and EclipseLink's moxy component can reuse it for the transformation to and from JSON keeping identity consistent in more complex object graphs

Comment: If you aren't going to use the ID or entities, then it doesn't matter which field you pick on an entity or that it is even unique.  Map any field as the ID.  You then can use that entity in JPA queries to get scalar results.  Or you can build non-entity objects using what are called constructor queries, of the form: "Select new Item(i.myField, i.myField2) from Item i" so that JPA builds objects for you.  These objects will not be managed in anyway though, and so not be cached etc, just basic flat  DTOs.

Comment: Hi, putting @Id on any field will produce weird behavior even with eclipselink.query-results-cache=false for native queries if the input parameters don't change but the output is supposed to change. It will still return the old result. We ended up trying to create composite keys (using IdClass) on field combinations that stay unique, that solved the issue. First, this is overhead we don't want to have just for the framework's purpose (because it does not make sense), second the case that field combinations are unique is not always the case. For that we already ended up assigning field manually

Comment: old results?  This should only happen if you are returning entities, which I mentioned you shouldn't do if you aren't going to setup a proper primary key.  Using the constructor queries should not return entities, but plain old java objects not managed, or cached by JPA.  If you are going to query on entities, it is a good idea in picking a unique ID and investing now as it will make life easier over all.  If you really can't find a unique set of fields, use the entire class itself.